# perl/sqlite cgi templates

Tags: perl

I am building a cgi page that prints out a table from sqlite. I have added features such as delete row, update row data with the website interface.

I was wondering if there are similar code available on the net? something like templates?

Someone must have done something similar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796232/whats-the-fastest-way-to-get-crud-over-cgi-on-a-database-handle-in-perl

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete).

Since you've tagged this question with 'perl', You could check out [CGI::CRUD](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI-CRUD/), but there are several ready-made packages available:

- http://www.sqlitemanager.org/
- http://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/
- http://phpsqliteadmin.sourceforge.net/